# Finding a unit vector orthogonal to two others using dot product

Tags: calculus, vectors

I came across this problem while learning about dot products.

> Find a unit vector that is orthogonal to both $\mathbf{i}+\mathbf{j}$ and $\mathbf{i}+\mathbf{k}$.

I know that two vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are orthogonal iff $\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}=0$. So I set up two equations

$$\begin{cases}(\mathbf{i+j})\cdot\mathbf{u}=0\\(\mathbf{i+k})\cdot\mathbf{u}=0\end{cases}$$
where $\mathbf{u}$ is the unit vector I'm trying to find, and $\mathbf{i},\mathbf{j}, \mathbf{k}$ are the standard basis vectors.

However, I'm not sure where to proceed from here. I tried solving it as a system by subtracting the two equations after expanding, but that didn't seem to work. I tried rewriting into the components, but that made things worse.

How do I approach this problem then? Anything advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What did you get when you wrote as components?  That's the way this problem should go.

Comment: Write $\mathbf{u}=a \mathbf{i} + b \mathbf{j} + c \mathbf{k}$.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to address the problem would be to use the cross product.

$$\begin{bmatrix}  1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}  1 \\ -1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$$

After which, you just have to normalize it.

Alternatively, solve the linear system,

$$u_1 + u_2 = 0$$

$$u_1 + u_3 = 0$$